# How to turn a string like "16/Sep/2014 08:34" to unix timestamp in PHP

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

Struggling without much success to turn strings like "16/Sep/2014 08:34" extracted from an array with explode command to unix timestamp like "2014-09-17 05:32:05" in PHP. Any help, please?

Edit: With @Erik's help I finally got the right result:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/M/Y H:i", $line[0]);
$date = $date->format('Y-M-d H:i');
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
```

Comment: What did you try that didn't work? You probably want an implementation of something like `strptime`.

Comment: Sorry for not being verbose the first time, corrected above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use DateTime::createFromFormat and then convert the resulting datetime to a timestamp by using $datetime->getTimestamp();

--

```
// this will create a generic PHP date object, which you can then manipulate into anything you want
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( "d/M/Y H:i", "16/Sep/2014 08:34" );

// this will generate a unix timestamp (which is an integer)
$timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();

// this will generate the string you request in your question
$string = $date->format( "Y-m-d H:i:s" );
```

--

For more info on formatting dates, check out the PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: I would really appreciate specific code example as otherwise if I knew how to use all those command I wouldn't post this. Thanks.

Comment: Something like the above should do it.

Comment: Erik, thanks, but I am getting now: Fatal error: Call to a member function getTimestamp() on a non-object in /home/dev/public_html/sites/all/modules/custom/server/server_stats/server_stats.module on line 53 which is "$timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();" Should've I mention that the string is extarcted from a text array with explode command.

Comment: Weird, it works for me. The error implies that the input string could not be converted to a datetime. You can try to run this immediately after createFromFormat and see what it comes up with:
print_r( DateTime::getLastErrors() );

It might be that your PHP language settings cause it to not recognize "Sep" as a valid month, or something along those lines.

Comment: It gives lots of  Array ( ) ) Array ( [warning_count] => 0 [warnings] => Array ( ) [error_count] => 0. If I just print my variable $line[0] then it correctly prints out "16/Sep/2014 08:34"

Comment: If I run print_r('<pre>'.date_parse($line[0]).'</pre>'); then it still gives lot's of Arrays, though print $line[0] is giving "16/Sep/2014 08:34"

Comment: After lots of tries and errors, I've got at least DateTime::createFromFormat("d/M/Y H:i", $line[0]); giving: DateTime Object ( [date] => 2014-09-16 08:34:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => America/Los_Angeles ) but is not there yet :(

Comment: That seems like you've properly converted the input into a date object; from there you can use the ->format function to convert into pretty much any string you might need. What's still going wrong?